# Cannot use datalab - getting error 403 when connecting in browser

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have tried to configure from scratch datalab with the free google cloud trial account.
I followed all steps here:
https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart

When I connect to my browser on localhost:8081, I get the following error:
403 Forbidden

I have tried to delete project, recreate one.
Change VM zone from europe-west to us-west with no luck.
I have also checked other post and made all account editor / owner of my project, same thing.
One thing i noticed is that when I create instance, I cannot choose 'y' when prompted to cache ssh key, and I have to press CTRL+C. Not sure if that makes a difference ? I tried from cmd and powershell, same issue.

```
Updating project ssh metadata.../Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/co
Updating project ssh metadata...done.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 7b:bd:14:9xxxx14:6c:a8
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) ^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Turned out I already had an http process (jabber) on port 8081...

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I already had an http process (jabber) on port 8081...